# Avoid CoyoteOutputStream object signature in spring rest file download call

Tags: java, rest, pdf, spring-restcontroller

I own a mock project maven spring-rest with the end point

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/{nid}/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public String getPjSae(@PathVariable String nid, @PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("NID : " + nid);
        LOGGER.info("NOM FICHIER  : " + fileName);
        File file = new File(saePath+File.separatorChar + fileName);
        LOGGER.info("CHEMIN PJ  : " + file);
        if (file.exists()) {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); //load the file
            // here I use Commons IO API to copy this file to the response output stream, I don't know which API you use.
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
            // here we define the content of this file to tell the browser how to handle it
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
        return response.getOutputStream().toString();
    }
```

I get the downloaded file and convert it to base64 to write it to an XML file. I have to make the comparison later and the problem is the writing of the signature of the object in the byte stream of the base 64: CoyoteOutputStream

At the end of each base64 of pdf I have a piece:

```
CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgo0NjkyOAolJUVPRgpvcmcuYXBhY2hlLmNhdGFsaW5hLmNvbm5lY3Rvci5Db3lvdGVPdXRwdXRTdHJlYW1ANDA4YTViYzI=
```

that is different each time because:

```
startxref
46928
%% EOF
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream@408a5bc2
```

So, this pit but comparison because : **@408a5bc2** is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You eventually return this:

```
return response.getOutputStream().toString();
```

This returns the default `toString` output for the output stream in question, i.e. your *CoyoteOutputStream object signature*. If you want to *avoid* this, don't return it.